# Problem in woocommerce 3.8.1, there is nothing in array POST

Tags: php, wordpress, post, woocommerce

I want remove tax from WooCommerce checkout if a custom field (my_fld) value exists.

I use this hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'Remove_Tax' );  

function Remove_Tax( ) {
    global $woocommerce;        
    if ( isset($_POST['my_fld']) ) $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( true ); 
}
```

but `$_POST` is always empty.

Comment: How you add custom feald?

Answer (score 0):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php to do the above -

```
function remove_taxexempt_checkout_based_field( $post_data ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( false );
    if ( isset($post_data['my_fld']) ) $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( true );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'remove_taxexempt_checkout_based_field' );
```